# unable to install parcel bundler through npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, parceljs

Unable to parcel bundler for my react project through npm package manager. While `npm i parcel-bundler`, the terminal is throwing error/warning saying

> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained
>   and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please,
>   upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

i tried to install core JS latest version, but that doesn't work.

Follwing message appears on installing parcel,

> deasync@0.1.19 install C:\Users\User\OneDrive\OneDrive
>   Laptop\Coding\YoutubeCode\V12 Dec 22 19 React
>   Boilerplate\node_modules\deasync
>
> > node ./build.js
>
> `win32-x64-node-10` exists; testing Binary is fine; exiting
>
> > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\User\OneDrive\OneDrive Laptop\Coding\YoutubeCode\V12 Dec 22 19 React
> >     Boilerplate\node_modules\core-js
> >     node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js )
>   for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!
>
> The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on
>   Open Collective or Patreon:
>
> > https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> >     https://www.patreon.com/zloirock
>
> Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking
>   for a good job -)
>
> > parcel-bundler@1.12.4 postinstall C:\Users\User\OneDrive\OneDrive Laptop\Coding\YoutubeCode\V12 Dec 22 19 React
> >     Boilerplate\node_modules\parcel-bundler
> >     node -e "console.log('\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove Parcel? You can now donate to our open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n >
> >     \u001b[34mhttps://opencollective.com/parcel/donate\u001b[0m')"
>
> Love Parcel? You can now donate to our open collective:
>
> > https://opencollective.com/parcel/donate npm WARN reactboilerplate@1.0.0 No repository field. npm WARN optional SKIPPING
> >     OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN
> >     notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
> >     fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
> >     {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> - parcel-bundler@1.12.4 added 736 packages from 535 contributors and audited 8431 packages in 279.429s found 0 vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

Your installation was actually successful.

if you add a "build" script in your package.json file (i.e. "build": "parcel build public/index.html" and then run "npm run build", it should work)

If you want to address the corejs issue you can use Parcel 2 (currently in beta). This may or may not work for you depending on what your project is, works great for me. (npm install --save-dev parcel@next).

A minor note, you probably mean to install parcel as a dev dependency (dependencies needed for building but not for running your app) That's what the --save-dev flag does for you. (shortcut is -D).